Apply seccomp filter without hobbling spawning process
Suppose we have a program spawner that is used to launch other programs with a seccomp filter. If one wants to deny the use of execve in app, could this be achieved by applying the filter to a thread within spawner and then spawner execves into app with the filter applied to app? If that won't work, then is there some other way that would?

Why not apply the filter just after fork(), before you exec()?

@TobySpeight Because a filter that denies execve will deny execve.

Oh, I see.  Of course!
